# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() installed one of the thrive themes

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed one of the thrive themes "rise", and this is the error I am getting when I hit customize theme, this was a clean install all plugins deactivated, installed their other themes the same problem

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function thrive_get_theme_options() in /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-content/themes/luxe/functions.php:643 Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): thrive_exclude_category(Object(WP_Query))
>   #1 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
>   #2 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
>   #3 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(1634): do_action_ref_array('pre_get_posts', Array)
>   #4 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(3222): WP_Query->get_posts()
>   #5 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(1704): WP_Query->query(Array)
>   #6 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php(1036): get_posts(Array)
>   #7 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php(622): WP_Customize_Manager->get_changeset_posts(Array)
>   #8 /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WP_ in /home/autoacc0/public_html/wp-content/themes/luxe/functions.php on line 643

Comment: I would reinstall WordPress and check PHP version of server

Comment: Don't downgrade your PHP version :( 

You'll be giving up a lot of performance, efficiency, features and security.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the theme, OR a plugin.

First, disable all unnecessary plugins, and try again with just the ORIGINAL LATEST theme.

Then, ensure you have the latest theme, plugins, and WordPress.

If that doesn't work, the theme likely has a bug and the developer needs to update it.

This is caused by the developer trying to use "thrive_get_theme_options" function before they included/required the PHP file (or if they use composer, didn't regenerate the class loader).

YOU can ATTEMPT to find the issue, and search the theme folder for that function (using a kind of recursive file contents search), and include the relevant php file (using REQUIREONCE) and if that fixes it, let the developer know of the fix and the need to update.

In normal practice, NEVER modify code you don't own. An update might undo your changes.

So, be wary of this, and "rename" the theme in the style.css file in the theme folder.

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme Name Here
Theme URI:
Description: Theme developed by a developer.
Author: The author of the theme
Version: 1.0
*/
```

This will create a "new" theme, so you don't break if an update is pushed.

There are posts suggesting to downgrade to a lower PHP version, DO NOT DO THIS.

Always stay on the latest version if you can. PHP7 is WAY faster and efficient and SECURE than PHP5.